# Navigation bar not showing iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am having multiple view controller in my application. I want to hide `navigationbar` in my first view controller. So I use the following code to hide the navigation bar

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true);
```

Now I want to add navigation bar in some other viewController but, my navigation bar not visible in that viewcontroller. Why it is happening?

My storyboard showing the navigation bar but once I try to run my application it is gone.

If I hide navigation bar from one view controller then we can't use navigation controller, Is it so? I hope I am wrong. Then what are the reasons for navigation bar not shown?

**EDIT:**

Also I want my view controller in portrait mode only. So I did the following Is that causing the issue?

```
extension UINavigationController{
    public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
            UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
            UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
                return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ,UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
    }
    

}
```

**Edit 1:**

I am  using following code to move from one view controller not link from the storyboard. Is that causing issue now?

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
        presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**Edit 2:**

Please check my following screenshots. Which are my settings for secondview controller

[image]

[image]

**Edit 3:**

Here is my navigation controller attribute inspector
[image]

Comment: you are setting on whole navigation controller stack so it will not be visible on view controllers which are placed on navigation controller. If you need to disable only on certain view controllers just do [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; in viewDidLoad method of the view controller

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Navigation Controller is a controller, which has stack of view controllers. So if you have something like this:

NAV -> A -> (segue) B

Even if you'll hide navigation bar you still should be able to make segues. Also can't you just unhide navigation bar in second (B) view controller in viewWillAppear? And in first the same way hide it on viewWillAppear.

edit: Final solution to the problem:
Use:

```
 let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller)
```

instead of:

```
let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Because pushViewController will add secondViewController to its stack. presentViewController was replacing your navigation controller that's why you couldn't see navigation bar.

Comment: So Is there no way to enable navigation bar again?

Comment: Why enable? You don't disable it in the first place. You just hide it like any other ordinary view. So you always can unhide it.

Comment: My other issue even I am not hiding my first navigation bar, navigation bar not visible in the second view controller.

Comment: Make sure you don't have second navigation view controller, but only one.

Comment: I changed that too. Could you please check my edit 1.

Comment: Please check my Edit 2: Am i miss anything?

Comment: Yes, it won't work that way. navigationController.pushViewController should do the work.

Comment: let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller)

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Now I am using like this         let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC");
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: false);
Why is that error?

Comment: So you don't have a navigation controller at all (it's nil). Do you use storyboard. It should look like this: NAV containing VC. in VC you can access self.navigationController object.

Comment: I have navigation controller for my initial view controller.

Comment: Please check my Edit 3

Comment: Show your storyboard with navigation controller and view controller.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. Please edit your answer with following code. Maybe that will help others. That is my mistake let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller)

Answer (score 25):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: I tried this not working. Could you please check my editted question.

Comment: Please check my Edit 2: Am i miss anything?

Comment: Thanks your logic is the perfect solution

Comment: Yes What i did wrong is I call new view controller like this  presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil). But I need to use this navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: false);. @Makalele find the error.

Comment: @Amsheer -- sry I foget to ask this, present view controller does not show/embed with  the navigation controller, if you want to perform this you need to manually embed with navigation controller . else you need to convert this into push viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for the easiest solution. Works for me

Comment: To support interactive pop gesture on navigation use with navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(<hidden: Bool>, animated: <the animated value fron viewWillAppear(animated)>)

Answer (score 7):

in viewDidLoad method of the view controller in which you don't want to show navigation bar add the line

```
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
```

you are presently hiding in all view controllers

Edit: You are presenting view controller instead it should be

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller)
```

Comment: you can use Objc-Swift converter (https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code) and post, your answer will be more helpful

Comment: Please check my Edit 2: Am i miss anything?

Comment: Your second view controller is not assigned to a class see your screen shot it does not show any view controller class assigned. And also you are presenting view controller. instead you need to push view controller
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller)

Comment: btw are you sure your second view controller is inherited from  UIViewController ?

Comment: Yes everything is viewcontroller but my issue i call like presntviewcontroller. I need to call like pushviewcontroller..

Comment: @harshayarabarla Please edit your answer with swift syntax.

Answer (score 6):

do like in `viewcontroller` based hidden using **Swift 4.0**

To hide `navigationController` in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

To unhide `navigationController` in `viewWillDisappear`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am having same requirement in my swift project.

**this is how I have handled Navigation bar**

Make sure your first screen is embedded into Navigation controller

[image]

example we have two screens A and B

In screen A you need to hide navigation bar in **viewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //hide navigation for screen A
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

for enabling Navigation in screen B
you need to add below code in screen A

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "screen B's segue identifier here")
        {
           //enable navigation for screen B       
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Using above style, I can enable or disable navigation bar for specific screen, whenever I want

Comment: What is kSEGUE_ID_MANAGE_ACCOUNT?

Comment: this is segue identifier for your next screen

Comment: I think I did something terribly wrong. I replace this "kSEGUE_ID_MANAGE_ACCOUNT" with "StoryBoard Id". Still no luck.

Comment: aah sorry, actually I use constant for segue, like this  **let kSEGUE_ID_MANAGE_ACCOUNT = "loadManageAccountSegue"**

Comment: It is still not working. Could you please check my edited question?

Comment: Just check your storyboard, first view is in Navigation controller (i have added screen shot), then check segue id for screen B, and then above code, clean build, it should perfectly work for Navigation, I can see this working in app.

Comment: I just embed first view controller so do I need to embed the second view controller again?

Comment: What is meant by segue id? Is it storyboard id?

Comment: My other issue even I am not hiding my first navigation bar, navigation bar not visible in the second view controller.

Comment: Please check my Edit 2: Am i miss anything?

Comment: @Amsheer SO dosn't allow long discussion here, lets join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95025/discussion-between-rdc-and-amsheer I will help you

Comment: Thanks I found solution.

Comment: @Amsheer glad to hear that :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have this navigation bar hidden only in this controller, the best way is to show it in `viewWillDisappear()` and hide in `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: I tried like that not working. Please check my Edit 2: Am i miss anything?

Comment: Thanks your logic is correct but i made mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to reply and there are other good answers but I would like to share what worked for me.

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller!, animated:true)
```